# How to rename various file extensions to .o in makefile?

Tags: makefile

Hi I have this makefile:

```
CC = gcc
AS = nasm

CFLAGS = -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector 
LDFLAGS = -m elf_i386 -T link.ld 
ASFLAGS = -f elf32

SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c wildcard src/*.s)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.[s|o]=.o)

INCLUDEPATH = -I inc src/include
OBJDIR = bin/obj
SRCDIR = src/

all: build

build:
   ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o bin/kernel.bin

iso: build
   cp bin/kernel.bin XeonOS/boot
   grub-mkrescue -o XeonOS.iso XeonOS/

run: iso
   quemu-system-i386 -m 512M -cdrom XeonOS.iso

clean:
   rm -rf bin/*.o bin/kernel.bin

%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c
   $(CC) $(INCLUDEPATH) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJECTS)

%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.s
   $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJECTS)
```

And when i execute the command make run i get the following error:

`ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld  src/kernel_c.c src/kernel_asm.s -o bin/kernel.bin
ld:src/kernel_c.c: file format not recognized; treating as linker script`

Because the kernel_c.c and kernel_asm.s didn' change their extension to .o. How can i change the extension of both .s and .c to .o at the same time?

By the way, I will have another problem, the value of the OBJECTS variable contains the src/ directory but the object files are stored in the bin/obj folder, How can i change that?

Comment: `$(SOURCES:.[s|o]=.o)` I don't recognise this "or" syntax. Where did you see this documented? Also presumably you intended `c` not `o` at the start there?

Comment: FWIW in the past I've just used separate variables for this. So, e.g. `SOURCES_C` and `SOURCES_S` then define separate conversions for them and concatenate into `$(OBJECTS)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes i intended c not o, about the [s|o], it was just an example so you can understand what i want, sorry for not saying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had this problem last month I just did this:

```
SOURCES_C := $(wildcard src/*.c)
SOURCES_S := $(wildcard src/*.s)
OBJECTS   := $(SOURCES_C:%.c=%.o) \
             $(SOURCES_S:%.s=%.o)
```

I haven't looked at this too deeply but, as far as I know, that's your best bet.

Comment: This feature is called "substitution reference" for anyone like me who wanted to find the page for it in the gnu manual.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used the @LightnessRacesinOrbit advice and also used patsubsr so the code is now working:

```
CC = gcc
AS = nasm

CFLAGS = -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS = -m elf_i386 -T link.ld 
ASFLAGS = -f elf32

C_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c)
C_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(notdir $(C_SOURCES) ))

ASM_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.s)
ASM_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.s,%.o, $(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES) ))

INCLUDEPATH = -I src/include
OBJDIR = bin/obj
SRCDIR = src/

.PHONY: build

all: build

build: $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)
   ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$(ASM_OBJECTS) $(OBJDIR)/$(C_OBJECTS) -o bin/kernel.bin

iso: build
   cp bin/kernel.bin XeonOS/boot
   grub-mkrescue -o XeonOS.iso XeonOS/

run: iso
    bochs -f bochsconfig.cfg -q

clean:
    rm -rf XeonOS/boot/kernel.bin
    rm -rf bin/obj/*.o bin/kernel.bin

%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDEPATH) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```